# PHP array isn't displaying in page

Tags: php, html, pdo

The list of notes should be displayed within the ul li spans, any reason as to why they aren't showing and instead the array is showing at the top of the page?

The database connection appears to be working perfectly fine, however the notes aren't showing within the spans. It also removes the 'you haven't added any notes text'

code

```
<?php

require_once 'app/init.php';

$notesQuery = $db->prepare("
    SELECT ID, note
    FROM notes
");

$notesQuery->execute();

$notes = $notesQuery->rowCount() ? $notesQuery : [];

foreach($notes as $note) {
    print_r($note);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>myNotes</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header> 
    <div class="container">
        <form action="add.php" method="post"> 
                <textarea name="note" placeholder="Insert a note..." autocomplete="off" required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
        <div class="notes">
            <h2>Notes</h2>

            <?php if(!empty($notes)): ?>

            <ul>
                <?php foreach($notes as $note): ?>
                    <li>
                        <span><?php echo $note['note']; ?></span>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p>you haven't added any notes yet.</p>
                <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: `print_r($notes);` before foreach loop.

Comment: Sorry whereabouts would I put this? If I put it before the `<?phpforeach($notes as$note): ?>` I receive ` PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT ID, note FROM notes )`

Comment: You've executed the statement, but you haven't `fetch`ed the rows.

Comment: What type of an object is $notes? Which database access library is this? I'm surprised you can just run a loop over the query without calling another method to extract the results? It looks like $notes is not an array but more like an iterator over the result set of the query, which you can use only once

Comment: @Joni Notes is a text object `$notes = $notesQuery->rowCount() ? $notesQuery : [];` is that not fetching the notes?

Comment: No if the query returned 5 rows then $notes = 5. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Please don't update your question with "FIXED" or similar edits. If you found the solution please post it as an Answer below - you are allowed to answer your own question. This is a Q&A site, please follow the format. Additionally, it allows people to upvote your answer, and also it shows up more in search results if there's an accepted answer, so it will be more helpful to other people (and likely attract more upvotes for you). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. In the meantime, I've rolled back your inappropriate edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Code

```
<?php

require_once 'app/init.php';

$notesQuery = $db->prepare("
    SELECT ID, note
    FROM notes
");

$notesQuery->execute();

$notes = $notesQuery->rowCount() ? $notesQuery : [];


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>myNotes</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header> 
    <div class="container">
        <form action="add.php" method="post"> 
                <textarea name="note" placeholder="Insert a note..." autocomplete="off" required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
        <div class="notes">
            <h2>Notes</h2>

            <?php if(!empty($notes)): ?>

            <ul>
                <?php foreach($notes as $note): ?>
                    <li>
                        <span><?php echo $note['note']; ?></span>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p>you haven't added any notes yet.</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to use below as an example for your query.

```
// Your sql query
$sql  = "SELECT ID, note FROM notes";

// Prepare your statement
$stmt = $db -> prepare($sql);

// Execute your prepared statement
$stmt -> execute();

// Retreive all rows
$notes = $stmt -> fetchAll();

// Check if array is not empty
if (!empty($notes)) {
    //Spit out the array
    print_r($notes);
}
```